# Connect to a SQL DB hosted on azure through a windows store app

Tags: c#, sql, azure, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I want to be able to connect to my DB on the azure platform and pull down some data from a table, using a windows store app in c#.
I have done this before in asp.net, but I know that the libraries for this type of thing are different when using windows store app.
Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Callum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to connect *directly* to your Azure database from a Windows Store app, because a firewall prevents direct access - you need to add each IP address individually. It would also be incredibly insecure.

Instead, create a simple API which your Windows Store app can call - use WebAPI in C# for example. You can host this on an Azure Web Site, and it can act as the gateway between your Windows Store app and the database.

Comment: Hey. Ok, so there is absolutely no way of creating a connection string (like in asp.net) to my azure DB? And then using that to write queries etc?

Comment: You still won't be able to connect to the database, even if you do have the right libraries and connection strings, because your user's IP won't be allowed through the firewall. You need to connect to your database via a website instead - your Store app will connect to your site via an API that you create, then your site is what connects to the DB.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. I shall take a look into it now. +1 :)

Comment: @user3744373 even if you could open-up firewall for everyone, and you would like app-store users to connect to your db directly, you'll need to give them username/password to your database. And once that information is out there, there will be no way to control what data is taken/modified in your database. Leading to a huge security issue.